# AngularJS ngRoute not working on mobile chrome

Tags: angularjs, google-chrome, angularjs-ng-route

I'm using AngularJS 1.4.7 for a web application which works completely fine on the desktop site. However when I load the page on my phone using Chrome the webpage doesn't load any of the routing that should be taken care of by the ngRoute component.

The header.php

```
<?php ob_start(); ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-ca" ng-app="ledgerFeed">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <title>Online Ledger</title>

    <script src="/res/jQuery.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/bootstrap/css/bootstrap-theme.css" />
    <script src="/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <base href="/ledger/">
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.7/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.7/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
    <script src="fetcher.js"></script>
    <script src="accountController.js"></script>
    <script src="entryController.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
```

The app.js

```
(function() {
    var app = angular.module("ledgerFeed", ["ngRoute"]);

    app.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {

        $routeProvider
//            .when("/", {
//                templateUrl: "accountlist.php",
//                controller: "accountController"
//            })
            .when("/accounts", {
                templateUrl: "accountlist.php",
                controller: "accountController"
            })
            .when("/account/:accountID", {
                templateUrl: "entrylist.php",
                controller: "entryController"
            })
            .otherwise({ redirectTo: "/accounts" });

//        $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

    });
})();
```

Does anyone know what I might be doing wrong ?

Comment: Connect your phone to your desktop and use Chrome's [remote debugging](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/remote-debugging) to look for any console errors

Comment: I have this issue too, did you fixed it?

Comment: @DonnyvanV Unfortunately no fix found for this issue yet.

Comment: @Jujunol im using angular touch which solved my issue: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngTouch